# How to detect if request is from application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is possible to detect, if request came from application and not from internet?

```
var send = function() {
    var request = http.request({
        path: '/recieve',
        port: 80,
        method: 'POST'
    }, function(res) {
        // ...
    });

    request.write('foo');
    request.end();
}

app.get('/recieve', function(req, res) {
    // here I need detect if request is from application
});

send();
```

Comment: The most simple check you could do is examining the value of the `User-Agent` header.  Keep in mind, this can be easily forged.

Comment: What do you mean by application exactly? Do you mean ensuring the request came from the client facing aspect of your application or do you mean what application is being used to view/interact with it, in which case what Tim mentions above is the place to start.

Comment: @TimCooper never trust a variable coming from HTTP end-user!